# R: pick up values based on a given timestamp and save as a new file

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset (i.e., measurements) over the past one year. The dataset were collected at 1-min interval. I realized that the difference at 1-min interval is larger than its system error. So, I want to pick up measurements that collected every 1 hour.

How to pick up measurements at 2015-07-08 02:30:00, 2015-07-08 04:30:00, ... etc?

The dataset looks like this:

```
          timestamp      tr      ts
 1   2015-07-08 02:29:00 1938.23 1978.62
 2   2015-07-08 02:30:00 1936.74 1979.25
 3   2015-07-08 02:31:00 1937.14 1978.99
 4   2015-07-08 02:32:00 1937.66 1978.83
 5   2015-07-08 02:33:00 1937.19 1979.15
 6   2015-07-08 02:45:00 1937.00 1979.00
 7   2015-07-08 02:46:00 1937.75 1979.29
 8   2015-07-08 02:47:00 1937.84 1978.44
 9   2015-07-08 02:48:00 1937.47 1979.17
 10  2015-07-08 02:49:00 1937.82 1978.68
 11  2015-07-08 02:50:00 1937.55 1979.60
 12  2015-07-08 02:51:00 1937.55 1979.13
 13  2015-07-08 02:52:00 1937.65 1979.12
 14  2015-07-08 02:53:00 1937.56 1978.28
 15  2015-07-08 02:54:00 1937.38 1978.99
 16  2015-07-08 02:58:00 1937.86 1978.61
 17  2015-07-08 02:59:00 1937.78 1978.85
 18  2015-07-08 03:00:00 1937.71 1978.68
 19  2015-07-08 03:01:00 1937.14 1979.04
 20  2015-07-08 03:02:00 1936.86 1979.43
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especially when you have a large dataset, I highly recommend `data.table`
 (both speed and usability).
The `data.table`-solution would be something like this (I assume that you want to have the values for the half-hour and not the average over the past hour):

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(df) # convert data.frame to data.table
# if timestamp is not POSIXct
# dat[, timestamp := as.POSIXct(timestamp)] # or use the package fasttime

# filter for entries where the time is half past.
filtered.dat <- dat[format(timestamp, "%M") == 30]
```

Does that help you?